# Corrupted compressed block contents at wrappedSendMessageCallback

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, next.js

I'm New to nextjs and I ran into a problem I added a  [TawkTo](https://www.tawk.to/?utm_source=tawk-messenger&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=referral&utm_term=5d7e91079f6b7a4457e1cadb) and I feel like this is the reason of the error. I have imported dynamically my tawkto file in my _app.js file :

```
import '../styles/Home.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Script from 'next/script';
import Head from 'next/head';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css';
import { SSRProvider } from '@react-aria/ssr';
import React from 'react';
import TawkTo from './Components/TawkTo';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const Countdown = dynamic(() => import("./Components/TawkTo"), {
    SSR: false,
  });
  return (
    <Head>
      <link passhref="true" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossOrigin="anonymous" />
      <Script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossOrigin="anonymous"></Script>
      <link passhref="true" rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossOrigin />
    </Head>,
    <SSRProvider>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Navbar />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <TawkTo />
        <Footer />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </SSRProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

and my TawkTo.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const TawkTo = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        // <!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
        var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {},
            Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();
        (function () {
            var s1 = document.createElement("script"),
                s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            s1.async = true;
            s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/5d7e91079f6b7a4457e1cadb/default';
            s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
            s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
            s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
        })();
        // <!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            {/* empty div  */}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TawkTo
```

and these are the console errors I'm getting:

[image]

a little help will be so much thankful :-)